# DateTime need convert to string wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<DataGrid....
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DateTime}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:d}}"  />
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
...
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Время оплаты">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding date_payment}"  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" />
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

but this column have type `DateTime`...
i need convert this column on this type(string), because i need rename value row on this column, i use event `LoadingRow` so

```
DataRowView item = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
DataRow row = item.Row;
var time = row[4];
if (Convert.ToString(time) == "01.01.0001 0:00:00")
{
   row[4] = "No payment";
}
```

but its wrong, row no converting to string, please help

Comment: Have you debugged the code? What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you have both a cell template and a data template. Pick one. Second, since you have a data template anyway there's no reason to create a converter, much less a code-behind event handler. You can keep all the relevant code and text strings (what if you need to localize?) nicely in one place with a trigger:

```
<DataTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DateTime}">
  <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:d}}"/>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Static DateTime.MinValue}">
      <Setter TargetName="text" Property="Text" Value="No payment"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if it's Nullable value you could use

```
Binding="{Binding date_payment, TargetNullValue={}Дата отсутствует}"
```

In case if not, use IValueConverter where you will check for MinDate.
Here is an [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136410/wpf-datagrid-displaying-image-in-column-using-converter-based-on-numerical-valu) how to use converters, and converter for you

```
public class DateConverter:IValueConverter
{
    private const string NoDate = "Дата отсутствует";
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is DateTime)
        {
            var date = (DateTime) value;
            if(date==DateTime.MinValue)
                return NoDate;
            return date.ToString();
        }
        return NoDate;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use Converter for this:

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            if (value == DateTime.MinValue) {
                return "No payment";
            }
            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Than just add the converter to your binding.