# wpf Datagrid Cell Formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Being completely novice to wpf, I am trying to get a datagrid cell formatted. I've found the following code and am playing with it, however, it does not do anything.

In this example, all I want to do is to format the columns that have a date in them. Could someone point me in the right direction???

My datagrid source is bound to a datatable in the code behind.

Please mindful that I may be using the wrong method to achieve my goal, so if you can advise what method  to use(in case the AutoGeneratingColumn is wrong)...

Thanks in advance.

```
private void DataGridBugLog_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    Style styleCenter = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontWeightProperty, "Bold"));
    style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, "Red"));

    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime))
    {
        (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
        (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).CellStyle = styleCenter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **style.Setters.Add** should be **styleCenter.Setters.Add**.

Your **"Bold"** should be **FontWeights.Bold**, and also **"Red"** should be **Brushes.Red**, you can use string in the xaml side as it can convert string to the type, while from code-behind, you need set the type.

The code below works for me as expected (but I would extract the Style if need to be reused for other cells)

```
if (e.PropertyType == typeof(System.DateTime))
{
    Style styleCenter = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));

    styleCenter.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
    styleCenter.Setters.Add(new Setter(FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold));
    styleCenter.Setters.Add(new Setter(ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red));

    (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
    (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).CellStyle = styleCenter;
}
```

Comment: Hi Eben, it works exactly as you've mentioned... The problem now is that the column that displays the date is not aligned with the header - I mean, the separator is out of alignment... Would you know what is causing it to behave this way??? I could send you a screenshot to explain better what I' trying to say here, but I don't know how to attach screenshots

Comment: Use the ElementStyle "var txtStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
                txtStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));
                (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).ElementStyle = txtStyle;"  instead of the "styleCenter.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGridCell.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center));"

Comment: Hi Eben, is there anyway you know of that I can identify the BugDateDetection column has "1/1/1753 00:00:00.000" in it and display null instead? private void DataGridBugLog_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Column.Header.ToString())
            {
                case "BugDetectionDate":
                    (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
                    (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).ElementStyle = txtStyleCenter;
                    break;
            }
        }

Comment: You can create a converter, then if the value is the specific date, return empty instead, otherwise return the date string, and you can remove the stringformat as well. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11468401/997453) for an example of the date converter. You can change the 'NoDate' to empty, change 'return date.ToString();' to 'return date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");' and then cast you ' (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding' to System.Windows.Data.Binding and set its converter.

Comment: I'm a total novice to xaml... I don't understand what you've said and how it is triggered. I used the LoadingRow method our colleague was having problems with... I've changed it as follows and it seems to work -  what do you think??? private void DataGridBugLog_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView item = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
            DataRow row = item.Row;
            DateTime resolutionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(row[12]);
            if (resolutionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/1753"))
                row[12] = DBNull.Value;
        }

Comment: With the converter, you can somehow config how your data get presented.

Comment: Just remove your stringformat line. add a new line '((e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding as System.Windows.Data.Binding).Converter = new DateConverter();' where the DateConverter is from the [link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/11468401/997453 , inside the Convert method, you can customise how your date get transformed to string (e.g. return empty string if the value is 01/01/1753.